# Is there a way to create HTML blocks with PHP via add-on installation?

Tags: php, cs-cart

I want to create HTML blocks and assign them to a specific grid whenever my add-on is installed.

I have tried to achieve this using SQL queries in `addon.xml` but I think this isn't a viable and elegant solution to my issue.

Comment: You mean like `echo "<hr>";`?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with what I'm asking. Please check this: https://docs.cs-cart.com/4.7.x/developer_guide/api/entities/blocks.html